# ssl handshake error while deploying google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-app-engine-python

I am getting the following error while deploying the google app engine

ERROR: gcloud crashed (SSLHandshakeError): [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics

I am using python 2.7 also tried turning off firewall settings but doesnot help. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have deactivated the antivirus that I was using and it seems to work. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common network issue seen when there is a networking proxy present on your network or antivirus and similar software that might prevent the connection.

As you mentioned the issue was solved when deactivating an antivirus software. If you still want to run the antivirus, you can configure it properly to allow the connection to GCP.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this to avoid SSL certificate validation and successfully worked
`gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation  True`